# Direct epub url to iBooks

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios5, epub

I know how to open epub books on an IOS device via UIDocumentInterationController and also via UIApplication openURL but....

What about grabbing a url to an epub on a remote server and from within my app rather than downloading the epub simply direct it to iBooks so that does the download thus only one copy eixts in the device...in iBooks library?